# QT3 (yes 3) integration with VS2003 (yes 2003), how to add new UI form to existing .proj

Tags: visual-studio, qt, qt3

I've been asked to do some updates to a QT3 app we've got and I need to add a new UI, I've created it in the QT .pro but it's not been picked up by the existing associated VS solution/.proj file. I think there ought to be some integration that can update the proj from the pro but I can't work out how to start it. I managed to get the new UI into the proj by manually editting the proj but I got linker errors and I'm not convinced I haven't missed something.

Moving to QT4/VS2010 isn't really an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use qmake to generate the .vcproj file in current subdirectory as follows:

```
qmake -tp vc
```

Make sure you keep the original .vcproj safe, there's no guarantee it was generated with qmake! Recall that there was a commercial Visual Studio plugin/add-in for Qt3. You may have it somewhere. I don't think it's freely downloadable.